# When averaging with Flutter, it also adds the null values ​to the average and the wrong result is obtained

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(blue)),
                onPressed: () {
                  double totalTeamAHome = calculateTotal(teamAHome);
                  double totalTeamAAway = calculateTotal(teamAAway);
                  double totalTeamBHome = calculateTotal(teamBHome);
                  double totalTeamBAway = calculateTotal(teamBAway);
    
                  int totalFilledFields = teamAHome.length +
                      teamAAway.length +
                      teamBHome.length +
                      teamBAway.length;
    
                  double average = totalFilledFields > 0
                      ? (totalTeamAHome +
                              totalTeamAAway +
                              totalTeamBHome +
                              totalTeamBAway) /
                          totalFilledFields
                      : 0.0;
                  // Hesaplandıktan sonra denetimcileri temizle
                  for (var controller in teamAAway) {
                    controller.clear();
                  }
                  for (var controller in teamAHome) {
                    controller.clear();
                  }
                  for (var controller in teamBHome) {
                    controller.clear();
                  }
                  for (var controller in teamBAway) {
                    controller.clear();
                  }
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('Average'),
                        content: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Text : ${(totalTeamAHome / teamAHome.length).toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                             
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Text :  ${(totalTeamBAway / teamBAway.length).toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                             
                            ),
                            Text(
                                'Text : ${(totalTeamBAway / teamBAway.length).toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                                ),
                            Text(
                                'Text : ${(totalTeamAHome / teamAHome.length).toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                                style: title),
                            Text(
                                'Text : ${average.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                                ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        actions: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Text('Close'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Calculate',
                  style: buttons,
                )),

      double calculateTotal(List<TextEditingController> controllers) {
    double total = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    for (var controller in controllers) {
      String text = controller.text.trim();
      if (text.isNotEmpty) {
        double value = double.tryParse(text) ?? 0.0;
        total += value;
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count > 0 ? total : 0.0;
  }
```

Let me explain the code I wrote and the code I want to write.

I am assigning 4 TextFormFields under the texts in a Row with the help of a FloatingActionButton. I enter certain numbers into these textFormFields and click the calculate button. After clicking the Calculate button, it shows me the average of the values ​​I entered in a showDialog, as I want.

Everything is fine so far, but if I don't write anything in the textFormFields, when I click the Calculate button, it sees these textFormFields as a value and adds it to the averaging process.

For example; Let me enter the value 5 in the first textFormField and the value 3 in the second. I don't type anything into the other 2 TextFormFields and click the calculate button.

What I want my code to do is operation (5+3)/2. However, it does (5+3) / 4 in the code. How do I prevent this? How do I make an empty TextFormField not be rendered

Comment: Make a list, filter the nulls.  Then divide by the shortened list length, not always by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
double calculateTotal(List<TextEditingController> controllers) {
  double total = 0.0;

  for (var controller in controllers) {
    String text = controller.text.trim();

    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      double? value = double.tryParse(text);

      if (value != null) {
        total += value;
      }
    }
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: No, it still averages blank fields.